# How the second and third equalities can be achieved?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

I am reading [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266751575_Tight_wavelet_frames_on_local_fields). In the Proof of Lemma 3.3,

1. How the second(*) equality can be achieved?
2. How can i use Parseval's identity in third(**) equality?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Second(*) inequality, follows from, $K=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}(\mathfrak{P}^{-j}+\mathfrak{p}^{-j}u(n))$.

For third (**), use Parseval's identity.

Comment: How can I prove that $K=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}(\mathfrak{P}^{-j}+\mathfrak{p}^{-j}u(n))$

Comment: How can i use Parseval's identity in third(**) equality?